# SQL Server exclusive select on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Let's say I am returning the following table from a select

| CaseId | DocId | DocumentTypeId | DocumentType | ExpirationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | I797 | 01/02/23 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | I94 | 01/02/23 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | Some Other Value | 01/02/23 |

I want to select ***ONLY*** the row with `DocumentType = 'I797'`, then if there is no `'I797'`, I want to select ***ONLY*** the row where `DocumentType = 'I94'`; failing to find either of those two I want to take all rows with any other value of `DocumentType`.

Using SQL Server ideally.

I think I'm looking for an XOR clause but can't work out how to do that in SQL Server or to get all other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
select *
from (
    select t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN DocumentType = 'I797' THEN 0 WHEN DocumentType = 'I94' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS prioorder
    from 
    (
        VALUES  
            (1, 1, 1, N'I797', N'01/02/23')
        ,   (1, 2, 2, N'I94', N'01/02/23')
        ,   (1, 3, 3, N'Some Other Value', N'01/02/23')
        ,   (1, 4, 3, N'Super Sekret', N'01/02/23')
    ) t (CaseId,DocId,DocumentTypeId,DocumentType,ExpirationDate)
    ) x
WHERE   x.prioorder = 1
```

The idea is to rank rows by 1, 2, 3 depending on document type. Since we rank "the rest" the same, you will get all rows if I797 and I94 is missing.

Comment: Yeh was thinking ranking, didn't know SQL Server had something like DENSE_RANK so thanks for highlighting that. Have managed to apply the above to my query. I think in this case rank = 1 will just give me I94s. I think what I effectively need is Rank = 0 XOR Rank = 1

Comment: I think it should work for what you wanted, if i understood you correctly. You can remove the various test values to test the results.

Comment: Might be misunderstanding but with x.prioorder = 1 that would return only I94s?

Comment: no. it returns whichever is the first inorder of importance, either i797,i94 or rest

Comment: Thanks tested and confirmed that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @siggemannen answer

```
select top 1 with ties
    case when DocumentType='I797' then 1
         when DocumentType='I94' then 2
    else 3
    end gr
   ,docs.*
from docs
order by 
    case when DocumentType='I797' then 1
         when DocumentType='I94' then 2
    else 3
    end
```

Shortest:

```
select top 1 with ties
   docs.*
from docs
order by 
    case when DocumentType='I797' then 1
         when DocumentType='I94' then 2
    else 3
    end
```

Comment: Oh, even better! I always upvote WITH TIES :)

Comment: I realised something though, both our solutions will return several rows if there are more than one I797 doc. I wonder if this is what the original user wants

Comment: That is acceptable for my current use case. Both your answers are good, is there a way to accept both?

Comment: Feel free to change the acceptable answer to this one, i think it's better performance-wise!

Comment: Both have similar query cost. Second answer query plan is shorter (https://dbfiddle.uk/cIvFFpKV). I think, it is not necessary to change the choice)

Comment: thanks! @siggemannen's query will have a single point of maintenance too i think, for my  purposes I will likely end up adding a lot of cases besides the two mentioned. would be easy to slip up and have them deviate in the above

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from YourTable where DocumentType = 'I797'
union 
select * from YourTable t where DocumentType = 'I94' and (not exists (select * from YourTable where DocumentType = 'I797'))
union
select * from YourTable t where (not exists (select * from YourTable where DocumentType = 'I797' or DocumentType = 'I94' ))
```

Comment: Thanks for working this out. Brain would not do it today. Might be asking a lot but is there any way to avoid the unions and compress it all into one outer reference?